# send image with curl

Tags: php, curl, directory

PHP

```
$filename=time().'.png';
$addressImage="/mahyapardaz/chap/tmp/".$filename;
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$prefix = 'http://';
$relative = '/mahyapardaz/viewer/add_pic.php';
$target_url =$prefix.$domain.$relative ;         
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath($addressImage);   
$fields = array(
                'code' => $code,
                'iddarkh        'insertdaste' =>  ($BPM_MahaleNameDarArchive["Daste"]),
                'insertnoe' =>  ($BPM_MahaleNameDarArchive["Noe"]),
                'codeMeli' =>  (''),
                'shemareSafhe' =>  ('1'),
                'newVersion' =>  (''),
                'image' =>  '@'.$file_name_with_full_path,
                );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

when set `@` for field name `image` curl does not worked and does not call the `app_pic` but when remove '@' from `image` this work well?
why?
perhaps `realpath` is not correct!?
and `var_dump($result)` equals to null.

Comment: Does the file exist? Looks like the name of the file being uploaded changes based on the time? `$filename=time().'.png'`

Comment: yes this file existed

Comment: What error do you get? What if you `var_dump($result)` after the curl_exec?

Comment: var_dump($result) is null

Comment: Well, there's not much information here for us to help you. Did you try var_dump on the `$file_name_with_full_path` first and did you try passing it to `file_exists` to check that it does exist? How about the script that you are uploading to (mahyapardaz/viewer/add_pic.php) maybe add some debugging to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.check for file exsited

```
if (file_exists($file_name_with_full_path)) {
    echo "The file $file_name_with_full_path exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $file_name_with_full_path does not exist";
}
```

2.

```
$file_name_with_full_path = realpath('.').'\\tmp\\'.$filename;
```